# Add footer info to a .sty or the .tex itself?

Tags: packages, fancyhdr

I can add footer information with the `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\copyright\hspace*{.1em}\the\year\hspace*{.1em}This company.}
\rfoot{Confidential. All Rights Reserved.}

\title{Brief Article}
\author{That Guy}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum
\section{Additional Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

and this gives me something workable:

[image]

What I'd like, however, is to dump the few lines that deal with the footer into a separate file so that a user can just call that file and not worry about the footers.  I thought it would have been as simple as putting those few lines into the `.sty` file associated with the `\documentclass{article}` class (renamed appropriately, moved to an accessible location, and called from within the `.tex` file), but when I run `pdflatex.exe` on the resultant `.tex` file, the build fails.

What I've done is copy the `\documentclass{article}` `.cls` and `.sty` files to a new directory, rename them to something new, and modify as necessary.  The modification, though, of adding the `fancyhdr` information to the `.sty` files causes the build to fail.  How can I remedy this?

Comment: if it fails then you did something wrong and tex would have given an error message, but you haven't shown what you did nor the error tex gave so it is hard to help.

Comment: oh do you mean you added it to `article.sty` ? that file isn't used at all (except for latex 2.09 emulation) you need to modify the renamed copy of article.cls

Comment: Holy smokes.  That was easy.  I added the footer information to the bottom of my `customNamed.cls` file and all worked perfectly.  Thanks @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: ..then tomorrow someone correct a bug in `article.cls` and you have to patch it in yours... I suggest writing a `mystuff.sty` package with you modification/macros/styles, and input it with `\usepackage{mystuff}` after loading the standard class. Unless you plan to make much more complex changes, that is.

Comment: An even better suggestion.  I had no idea that creating my own package was so simple.  Some quick edits of my `customNamed.cls` file and a new `.sty` file and I can revert to using the original `article.cls` but with my new `.sty` file.  I'm in the steepest part of the LaTeX learning curve; I'm getting there, but sometimes I can be dense.  Thanks for your help, @Rmano and @DavidCarlisle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you added it to `article.sty` ? that file isn't used at all (except for latex 2.09 emulation) you need to modify the renamed copy of `article.cls`

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm very new to LaTeX but have been learning quite a bit over the last few weeks.  Every new bit of information helps.

Comment: @Steven note I answered the question as asked but I _wouldn't_ advise starting from a copy of `article.cls` it wastes disk space and means you don't pick up bug fixes. You can make a small `foobar.cls` that _just_ does `\LoadClass{article}\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}` then has your definitions.

Comment: @Rmano made a suggestion above that I thought was above my knowledge base.  However, in trying it, it turned about to be very easy.  I've done that instead.  Now, I'm using the original `article.cls` and just including `\usepackage{MyPackage}`.